# DAX to flag expired record

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

I want to write a dax where if my overrun value is greater then 0 and final complete date is empty and planned finish date is in past is flag my record as Overrun by number of days.

Desired Output

Need the flag Columns to show if Loc_id has an overrun by how many days.
[image]

Comment: Please paste sample data as copiable text.

Comment: Loc_id Planned start date Planned finish date Final Complete date OverRun age Flag
1 28/12/2022 03/01/2022 02/01/2022 -1 Complete
2 03/01/2022 09/01/2022 06/01/2022  Complete
3 04/01/2022 06/01/2022  3 Overun

Comment: Update your question rather than posting a comment. Can you post a desired output too as your question isn't clear to me.

Comment: not letting me past the in copiable text

Comment: i got this dax Status = If(TODAY()>palnnedfinishdate && ISBLANK(finalcompleteddate),"Overrun")

Answer (score 0):

Used Below DAX

Status = If(TODAY()>palnnedfinishdate && ISBLANK(finalcompleteddate),"Overrun")